# Show that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty iP[X>i]=\frac12( E[X^2]-E[X]) $ for every positive integer valued random variable $X$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Let $X$ be a non-zero random variable with values in $\{1,2,3,...\}$. Proof the next equality: $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}iP\left[X>i\right]=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\left( E\left[X^{2}\right]-E\left[X\right]\right) $$I don't know how can I do it this proof.

Comment: Hint: Do you know how to prove that $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P\left[X>i\right]=E\left[X\right]\ ? $$ If you do not, this is the question you should be trying to solve, instead of the more elaborate version above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i\mathbb{P}(X>i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i\sum_{n=i+1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X=n) $$
and interchange the sums.